# How to set source version of Java library in Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, java-8

I've got an Android project split into a **pure Java** library and the Android application. I'm using [Gradle Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) so I can write Java 8 code.

Android Studio 1.3 correctly recognises the `android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility` in the Android module that I've set to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`.

Now I'd like Android Studio to realise the Java module is also Java 8. I've tried (in the root of the Gradle script, after `apply plugin 'java'`:

1. `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` But doesn't work. Gradle correctly compiles, but Android Studio shows a warning ("Assignment not used") and assumes Java 6.
2. `sourceCompatibility 1.8` doesn't compile.

How can I get Android Studio to recognise this without resorting to the "Set source version" quick fix? Or is it unimplemented for now?

**EDIT**

To clarify, the whole project *does* compile with `./gradlew assembleDebug`. The problem is with Android Studio source highlighting.

My Java module build.gradle is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.12'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-string:1.0.0'

    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

retrolambda {
    jdk System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
    defaultMethods true
    incremental false
}
```

And here's what Android Studio gives me:
[image: Android Studio highlighting error]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would appear (thanks @Anand Singh) that Android Studio doesn't handle this yet, so you need to apply the quick fix.

Comment: Sorry, what is your quick fix?

Answer (score 0):

in your java module `build.gradle` write code like this:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {


}

retrolambda {
    jdk System.getenv("JAVA8_HOME")
    defaultMethods true
    incremental false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's already working in the Android module. I have a pure Java module that I'm working with.

Comment: My project already compiles (I pretty much have that code); Android Studio syntax highlighting thinks there's a problem.

Comment: @ThorinII remove `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` from your java module. Second ignore that error in java module. Me too getting same but do not worry about that. add `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` to your main app build.gradle file. After these changes do clean and rebuild.

Comment: @ThorinII if issue solved please do accept answer :)